# Azure kudu documentation

Tags: azure, kudu

Kudu is an important tool for App Service in Azure.
It handles deployment and also serves as a layer between the server on which an application lives and a developer, while the server is hidden from the developer as it is a [managed service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_services).

[This](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) page provides general documentation.

This tool, as I know after a couple of years using it, has much more capabilities and internal particularities. Right now, for instance, I was zip-deploying an Azure Function to a slot and the deployment never ended. Then I deleted the `deployments` folder and the deployment succeeded. I know this because I already stumbled upon this issue.

Where can I find an in depth documentation of kudu and the use cases of features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've linked to the docs page, basically. thats the best you can get. there are additional bits and pieces scattered across learn.microsoft.com, but generally [that](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) is the place.

Not sure why are you unhappy, its pretty thorough.

Comment: Your answer seem to be the only one. If no one answers I will mark it as correct on Monday.